# How do you determine if a value is statistically significant?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

I have collected some data I need to analyze. The data is the result of a survey in which I asked approx. 180 sellers at a bazaar, how important a certain buyer's characteristic is in relation to their price setting on a scale from '1 = absolutely unimportant' to '10 = extremely important' (for instance, how important is a buyer's nationality in relation to the price a merchant is offering his goods).

I now have analyzed my results and clustered the data, where it was necessary, but I do not know at which point a value gets statistically important.

Should I separate the data into two groups, one for answers below 5 and one for above, or in three groups (1-3,4-7,8-10) and at how many percent is something statistically important? Is one characteristic significant important, if 80% of the answers were 8 and above, is it still if there are just 60% above?

Edit: Ok let me clearify my question: I do not want to compare two chracteristics to each other. I am using R and I created histograms with density lines and also cummulative density lines to present my data. The problem is, that I do not know how I can say wether  one particular characteristic is important or not. Do I need to focus on their means? And how does their standard deviation affect the interpretation?
I have conducted a survey in one particular bazaar with approx. 3600 merchants, meaning I have the answers of 5% of them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue here. The standard technique would be to use a histogram to approximate a distribution. Could you provide more details?

Comment: The issue of statistical significance arises when you're comparing two groups or when you're assessing whether a given value is likely to be different from some reference value. It's hard to tell from your question what you're trying to find out. Are you just interested in the mean response for each question or are you interested in checking whether there are statistically significant differences in the mean response when comparing different questions (e.g., is buyer's characteristic A more important than characteristic B)?

Comment: Also, what is your universe of sellers? Is it just the sellers at this particular bazaar or do you hope to generalize to sellers at other bazaars? Do the 180 sellers you surveyed represent nearly all the sellers at the bazaar or a small sample of them?